# Moq & C#: Invalid callback. Setup on method with parameters cannot invoke callback with parameters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

The actual interface signature goes like this

```
Task<GeneralResponseType> UpdateAsync(ICustomerRequest<IEnumerable<CustomerPreference>> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ILoggingContext loggingContext = null);
```

Testcase:

```
ICustomerRequest<IEnumerable<CustomerPreference>> t = null;
CancellationToken t1 = new CancellationToken();
LoggingContext t2 = null;
this.customerPreferenceRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.UpdateAsync(
        It.IsAny<ICustomerRequest<IEnumerable<CustomerPreference>>>(),
        It.IsAny<CancellationToken>(),
        It.IsAny<LoggingContext>()))
    .Callback<ICustomerRequest<IEnumerable<CustomerPreference>>,CancellationToken, LoggingContext>((a, b, c) => { t = a ; t1 =b;t2= c; });
```

The setup is throwing an exception in the testcase,as below

> Invalid callback. Setup on method with parameters
>   (ICustomerRequest`1,CancellationToken,ILoggingContext) cannot invoke
>   callback with parameters
>   (ICustomerRequest`1,CancellationToken,LoggingContext).

What is wrong I am doing?

I have verified [Moq: Invalid callback. Setup on method with parameters cannot invoke callback with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18927609/moq-invalid-callback-setup-on-method-with-parameters-cannot-invoke-callback-wi)

But I didn't see any help.

Comment: It should be `ILoggingContext` not `LoggingContext`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the `Callback` parameters used do not match the method definition. Even though the `Setup` uses `It.IsAny<LoggingContext>` the method definition uses `ILoggingContext` parameter

Change `t2` to

```
ILoggingContext t2 = null;
```

And update the `Callback` to

```
.Callback<ICustomerRequest<IEnumerable<CustomerPreference>>,CancellationToken, ILoggingContext>((a, b, c) => { 
    t = a; 
    t1 = b;
    t2 = c; 
});
```

or

```
.Callback((ICustomerRequest<IEnumerable<CustomerPreference>> a, 
           CancellationToken b, 
           ILoggingContext c) => { 
        t = a; 
        t1 = b;
        t2 = c; 
    });
```

Either way will work.

I would also advise that the `Setup` return a completed `Task` so as to allow for the test to flow asynchronously as expected.

```
this.customerPreferenceRepositoryMock
    .Setup(x => x.UpdateAsync(
        It.IsAny<ICustomerRequest<IEnumerable<CustomerPreference>>>(),
        It.IsAny<CancellationToken>(),
        It.IsAny<LoggingContext>()))
    .Callback((ICustomerRequest<IEnumerable<CustomerPreference>> a, 
               CancellationToken b, 
               ILoggingContext c) => { 
                    t = a; 
                    t1 = b;
                    t2 = c; 
                    //Use the input to create a response
                    //and pass it to the `ReturnsAsync` method
             })
    .ReturnsAsync(new GeneralResponseType()); //Or some pre initialized derivative.
```

Review Moq's [QuickStart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better understanding of how to use the framework.